# .NET Core GetEnvironmentVariable variable returns null

Tags: azure-functions, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Working with Azure Functions. For some reason GetEnvironmentVariable always returns null in JetBrains Rider. However it does work fine in VS2022. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That can be a bug and you should discuss with JetBrains via https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Comment: @ShaneKm provide function code in text format.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change MSBuild version in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build > MSBuild version** to the one you are using in the Visual Studio?